# How to make the turret focus the clone of Wukong? (decoy ability)

Tags: league-of-legends

I know it's possible, but although I main Wukong I've never been able to do it properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot drop the aggro once you've gained it since the turret has True Vision and you become stealthed with your W and not Untargetable.

Your clone works pretty much like a Mordekaiser Ghost or a Shaco clone. It counts as a champion but also as a pet which puts it pretty high on the priority list of turrets.

The only way to get the turret to focus your clone is by using the ability right before the last of your minions dies. Also keep in mind that any damage to a champion before or after you cast your spell will let the turret focus you again which requires walking out of range in order to drop aggro.

Comment: @Pierre Yup I clarified it.

Comment: meeeeeeh don't compare it with shaco... because he will drop turret aggro when using R. this might confuse people.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Well it's how the clone works not the spell. Shacos R makes him disappear for .25 seconds while Wukongs W stealthes him. The clones still work pretty much the same (they block stuff like Ashe Arrow and Caitlyn Ult)

Comment: yes. i just wanted to clarify it ... the CLONES work in the same way. the ABILITIES dont.

Answer (score 2):

You also used to be able to accomplish this by timing flash between turret shots such that the turret would be unable to target you, and thus, target your clone instead (or another nearby creep/champion).

You can see an example of this in action:

Around the 0:15 mark, Cassiopiea flashes, which causes the turret to fire at Nunu instead (just imagine 2 Wukongs, rather than Nunu/Cass).

This "bug" was fixed around the time the new season started though.

Comment: A shame we can't do it anymore! =) but thanks!